# Group dictionaries based on values that differ

Tags: python

Grouping dictionaries based on similar values is easy, but I have trouble thinking of a good way of doing the opposite: grouping dictionaries where one of the key's value differ from the rest.

For instance, take these:

```
a = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3:'c'}
b = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3:'d'}
c = {1: 'c', 2: 'b', 3:'d'}
```

These can be grouped into two different sets, where one of the key values differ:

```
# Expected output:
{3: {a, b},    # Differs on 3
 1: {b, c}}    # Differs on 1
```

I have trouble thinking of a good way of implementing such a function. Do you have any suggestions about how to go forward?

Comment: So, what is the expected output ? and what about {a, c}

Comment: @sjcipher I made it a clearer of what I expected to be outputted.

Comment: And why would your output not be `{3: {a, c}, 1: {a, c}}`?

Comment: @doukremt: Those are the keys for which the listed dict values differ

Comment: i think in his case, `{a,c}` differ by more than one item, so he doesn't want to track them.

Comment: Using the same character as variable name, and values of keys confused me here...

Answer (score 3):

You can get a dictionary difference, assuming that the keys and values are hashable, by usings sets on the items. You can then get a list of pairs of dicts, and what their difference is:

```
a = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3:'c'}
b = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3:'d'}
c = {1: 'c', 2: 'b', 3:'d'}

def diff_dict(dicta, dictb):
    aset = set(dicta.items())
    bset = set(dictb.items())
    diff = aset ^ bset
    return tuple(set(x[0] for x in diff))

print diff_dict(a, b)
(3,)

all_dicts = [a,b,c]

listgroup = []

for dicta, dictb in itertools.combinations(all_dicts, 2):
     key = diff_dict(dicta, dictb)
     listgroup.append((key, (dicta, dictb)))
```

If you only want single items, gate the append with an `if len(key) == 1`.

Comment: Wow this is great! `itertools` seems more and more interesting everytime I see it :)